# Implementation error for type bool when writing custom Ansible module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to write a custom module in Ansible 2.3 to use in my playbook. The details of it has been abstracted to run a minimal `date` command below, but I'm developing a much complicated example.

```
[dev@foobar Gist]$ tree ansible_version_err/
ansible_version_err/
├── dev_command.yml
└── library
    └── dev_command.py
```

The contents of the library file is using the `ansible.module` package to implement the custom command.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec={
            'command': { 'type':'str', 'required': True },
            'print_elapsed': {  'type':bool, 'required': False },
            'print_time': { 'type':bool, 'required': False } } )

    stdout = None
    stderr = None
    rc = None

    try:
        time_start = time.time()
        proc = Popen( module.params['command'], shell = True)
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
        time_end = time.time()
        rc = proc.returncode

        if rc != 0:
            raise Exception("error while obtaining date")

        time_elapsed = time_end - time_start

        if 'print_elapsed' in module.params and module.params['print_elapsed']:
            stdout = stdout + "\nelapsed time: " + str(time_elapsed)

        if 'print_time' in module.params and module.params['print_time']:
            stdout = stderr + "\ntime: " + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', time.gmtime(time_start))

        module.exit_json( changed = False, stdout = stdout, stderr = stderr, rc = rc, time_elapsed = time_elapsed  )

    except Exception:
        pass
```

and the `.yml` file using this `dev_command` is called as

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: testing a custom command
    vars:
      print_stdout: True
    dev_command: command="{{cmd}}" print_elapsed=True print_time=True
```

I'm just calling the `cmd` with `date` which will go ahead and run the date command.

```
ansible-playbook dev_command.yml -vvv -e "cmd=date"
```

While I expect this work on Ansible 2.3, it is throwing me an error as

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "command": "date", 
            "print_elapsed": "True", 
            "print_time": "True"
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "implementation error: unknown type <type 'bool'> requested for print_time"
}
```

This error is not seen in v2.6. Why is this happening? Is this a known Ansible feature bug that can only be resolved by moving to a newer version. Version details

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.3.0.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"On Ansible 2.3, it is throwing me an error ... This error is not seen in v2.6. Why is this happening? Is this a known Ansible feature bug that can only be resolved by moving to a newer version?"*

A: Yes. It's necessary to move to a maintained version. Even if it was a known problem it wouldn't be fixed anymore. Ansible [Release cycle](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#release-cycle) says:

> *"Ansible has a graduated maintenance structure that extends to three major releases ... we strongly encourage you to upgrade as soon as possible ..."*

The latest Ansible version is 2.9 at the moment. The last maintained version is 2.7 at the moment.

---

FWIW. The command

```
$ grep -r type /scratch/ansible/lib/ansible/modules/ | grep bool | grep defaul
```

shows all modules declare the type Boolean with quotation

```
type='bool'
```

or

```
'type': 'bool'
```

Comment: While this makes sense, I would like to understand why this was throwing an error and what was fixed in the newer versions. I've seen a sort of similar issue here - https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/2538, but not able track, which Ansible version the fix was patched to

Comment: The fix seems to be the quotation of the value  `type='bool'`.